# Conventional boolean tests

Tags: javascript

**Question**

> Although you can explicitly check if a value is true or false, it's a convention in JavaScript to test against all falsy values. For example, we can test if a variable value is falsy by testing if (value).

**Code**

```
function UnconventionalDefaults(params, defaultParams) {
  if (params === undefined) {
    params = defaultParams;
  }

  // function would do work here

  return params;
}

// Modify this function to set params to defaultParams if params
// is falsy
function moreConventionalDefaults(params, defaultParams) {
  // do a more conventional check here (check if params is falsy, 
  // and not just undefined
  if(params === undefined){
    params === defaultParams;
  }else if(params === null){
    params === defaultParams;
  }else if(params === ""){
    params === defaultParams;
  }else if(params === false){
    params === defaultParams;
  }

  return params;
}
```

Although I'm testing against all the falsy values, this code is not being accepted. What is it that I'm doing wrong? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You forgot 0, which is also falsy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- You cannot use `===` for assigning into params. Use `=` instead.
- Also those are not all falsy values, you are missing `0` and `NaN`.

The whole method can be simplified into:

```
function moreConventionalDefaults(params, defaultParams) {
  return params || defaultParams;
}
```

`params` will be evaluated and if it is falsy then the `defaultParams` will be returned.

EDIT: Have a loot at great article [**Exploring JavaScript’s Logical OR Operator**](http://addyosmani.com/blog/exploring-javascripts-logical-or-operator/) by Addy Osmani for more information.

Comment: Oh god, such a stupid mistake. I'm sorry for this question. -.-

Comment: @Rafay: It is fine. Some readers can now learn a bit more about falsy values and how to make code shorter using `||` :).

Answer (score 3):

Try this one, please

```
function moreConventionalDefaults(params, defaultParams) {
    if (!params) params = defaultParams;
    return params;
     // or just 
    return params || defaultParams;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to test for all falsy values is to use an explicit `if` statement.  For example

```
if (params) {
  // Truthy
} else {
  // Falsy 
}
```

I'll leave the rest to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is asking for;

```
function moreConventialDefaults(params, defaultParams) {
    if (!params) {
        params = defaultParams;
    }
}
```

An `if` statement executes the statement if the condition evaluates to `true` (i.e. is truthy), otherwise it'll execute the `else` condition.

So by negating the `params` parameter (`!params`), we're executing the statement only if the condition evaluates to `false` (i.e. falsy), which is what the question is asking for.

Comment: I think you swapped `params`/`defaultParams`.

Comment: @balkon_smoke: Beat you to it :)

Comment: @Rafay: That's weird. I'd bet money that's what the question's asking for.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was using === signs to assign the values instead of the assignment operator =. Didn't notice it there.